# Grouping Array by Value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, data-structures

I am looking to group my array into sub arrays when they have the same Supplier ID. I have looked at many similar questions on here but I cannot get any of them to work for me. I have tried foreach loops and even the PHP merge function. I have to use MySQLi for this so I cannot group using PDO.

This is what I have:

```
Array
(
    [supplierID] => 1
    [drugID] => 1
    [costPrice] => 9.98
    [reorderQTY] => 50
)

Array
(
    [supplierID] => 1
    [drugID] => 2
    [costPrice] => 9.98
    [reorderQTY] => 50
)

Array
(
    [supplierID] => 2
    [drugID] => 3
    [costPrice] => 9.98
    [reorderQTY] => 50
)
```

This is what I need:

```
Array
(
    [supplierID] => 1
        Array
            (
                [drugID] => 1
                [costPrice] => 9.98
                [reorderQTY] => 50
            )
                [drugID] => 2
                [costPrice] => 9.98
                [reorderQTY] => 50
            )
)


Array
(
    [supplierID] => 2
        Array
            (
                [drugID] => 3
                [costPrice] => 9.98
                [reorderQTY] => 50
            )
)
```

This is the PHP where I am outputting the array to get the above result:

```
if(isset($_POST["automatic"])){

    $sql = "SELECT supplierID,drugID,costPrice,reorderQTY FROM drugs WHERE quantityInStock <= reorderLevel"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($row);// I need to sort this array into sub array groups by supplierID key
            echo "</pre>"; 



        }
    }else{
        echo " <tr><td>0 results </td></tr>";
    }   
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: what does pdo have to do with grouping? grouping is something you do in sql, and pdo is just there to send sql to the db server. it couldn't care less if you do grouping or not. it's not pdo's job to do that.

Comment: You can't get an array to look like the one you want. It's an invalid markup. You can't have multiple keys with the same name ("supplierID"). And you can't have both an integer and an array in the same key..  @Tom Millards response below is the way you should go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do it,

```
    $out = [];           
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $out[$row->supplierID][] = $row;
    }
```

Basically I use the supplier id to create an array key, then assign an empty array. Then add all rows with that supplier id to that array.

This will create a multidimensional array.

Comment: The if statement is obsolete; those two lines are irrelevant and can be removed. You should always use curly braces to aid readability too.